# Python, handling 3D printing text

Tags: python, regex

I would like to handle string output from 3D printer about temperatures in a Python.
Output example:

```
"217.2/230  215.4/240 B:40/55"
```

Before `/` is actual temperature and after `/` is reguired temperature.
Temperatures before `B:` are for hotends after `B:` is for bed.

There can be several hotends, but always just one bed. Example for 1 hotend 3d printer:

```
215.4/240 B:40/55"
```

4 hotend example:

```
"217.2/230 218.2/240 238.1/240 215.4/240 B:40/55"
```

I would like to handle this string output and save just actual temprature (before `/`) to variables like HotEnd1, HotEnd2, max. HotEnd4, and a one Bed variable...

Thank you for any solution or advice. I dont know where to start.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Please try to describe your problem both *with* and *without* the use of examples, and use paragraphs to structure your question instead of just posting a wall of text.

Comment: Also, have you tried anything at all? If so please post your code. There are millions of ways to split strings and assign parts of them to separate variables, `regex` is one of them. Or you could go for something as crude as `yourString.split('B').split('/')` (not tested). Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that returned two values, the bed temperature and a list of the hotend temps:

```
def parse3D(s):
    bed, hotends = None, []
    for pair in (t.split('/') for t in s.split()):
        if pair[0].startswith('B:'):
            bed = pair[0].split(':')[1]
        else:
            hotends.append(pair[0])
    return bed, hotends

data = "217.2/230 218.2/240 238.1/240 215.4/240 B:40/55"
bed, hotends = parse3D(data)
print bed, hotends  # -> 40 ['217.2', '218.2', '238.1', '215.4']
```

If you desired, you could convert the number strings into`float`or`int`values in the function as well.

Answer (score -1):

This could be done with regex:

```
import re
test = '217.2/230 218.2/240 238.1/240 215.4/240 B:40/55'

matches = re.findall("(?:(?:(B:)?(\d+\.?\d+)/))+", test)
results = {'hotend': []}
for b, temp in matches:
    if b:
        results['bed'] = temp
    else:
        results['hotend'].append(temp)

print results
# {'bed': '40', 'hotend': ['217.2', '218.2', '238.1', '215.4']}
```